Find original matrix given cofactor matrix
This is my first question on the Math StackExchange. I'm working on a problem in (high) school on linear algebra. Our teacher gave some of us the following question (that is supposed to be a challenge for us:
"Given only the cofactor matrix C of an original matrix A, find the original matrix A.
$$\text{C} = \begin{bmatrix}243 & 315 & -183 & 99\\ -774 & 321 & 659 & -498\\ 225 & -165 & 272 & -228\\ 135 & -99 & -330 & 603\end{bmatrix}$$"
He told us that this question was designed to be done very simply, without a calculator, as a bonus question at the end of a test (last ~10 min) he had previously given. The only thing is, neither he nor I knows the answer as I've been stumped about this question and he forgot just what exactly the solution was after throwing some of his materials.
I'm aware that $\text{adj}(\text{A}) = \text{C}^T$ and that $\text{A}^{-1} = \dfrac{1}{\text{det}(A)}\text{adj}(\text{A})$, and I feel like they have something to do with solving this matrix, but I'm not sure how. I also know that $\text{det}(\text{adj}(\text{A})) = \text{det}(\text{A})^{n-1}$ and that $\text{adj}(\text{adj}(\text{A})) = \text{det}(\text{A})^{n-2}\text{A}$, but I'm not sure if they will help given that the numbers are relatively large to do out by hand.
The solution can probably be brute force, and my teacher acknowledges that, but it would be difficult to do that in the constraints this problem was designed for. Any insights are appreciated. Thank you very much!
